# Retrieve data from SQLite in a ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, onclick

Hi guys so I have this doubt. I've created an app that stores data in a SQLite and its displayed on a Listview in the Main Activity. What I'm trying to do is once I click one item from the list it should open an image from sd card. So my question is how can I use onClick here since I don't know the longitude of the list? And may I include the onclick for the list in the switch I've got?

UPDATED:
I forgot to say that that I would like to open an image stored in the sdcard when I click a item of the list.

That's what I've got for now:

```
    Contact_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("lat"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

All comments or suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle the click event in Listview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnItemClickListener()` method:

```
Contact_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int selectedIndex, long arg3) {       
    }
);
```

Comment: But the only I can get is the id of the selected item. Is there any way I could get the content of the item?