# onItemClick - Intent constructor

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I got stuck with an error while writing this part of code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.toDoListView);
    lv.setAdapter(tdla);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);//<--- Cannot resolve constructor
            newIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "TETTE");
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
    });
```

I thought Intent constructor should be the same as declaring it in a simple function linked to a Button as:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);//<--- OK
    ...sth...
    startActivity(newIntent);
}
```

Also [How to handle the click event in Listview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android) shows a similar example but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);//<--- Cannot resolve constructor

    }
});
```

to for activity

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    }
});
```

and for fragment

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with the first one. But why in this case I have to use `getApplicationContext()` instead of the Activity?

Comment: you can use  both , getApplicationContext() return a context and activity.this also

Answer (score 1):

replace "this"

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

or for fragment

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your intent :

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

to this :

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Don't use "this" keyword with intent when you are using intent inside any click listener.

Answer (score 1):

You are inside the Itemclick listener, which has no context (no Activity).

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class)
```