# Inserting Text Into EditText With Custom Inputmethod

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am trying to create my custom input method.
I created my custom inputmethod on android and now I want that when a user clicks on a view a text insert in focused edit text. How can in do that ?

This is my code :

```
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (ViewGroup) G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard_list, root);
    ListView lstKeyBoard = (ListView) kv.findViewById(R.id.lstMain);
    MyListView.setLV(G.db, lstKeyBoard, "main");
    return kv;       
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=handle+listview+clicks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8  see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android

Comment: i created somthinf like that https://s.cafebazaar.ir/1/upload/screenshot/com.meehrdad.voicekeyboard11.jpg   now i need when user click on any button a text insert into edittext its not about listview

Comment: edittext.setText(edittext.getText+"your_text");