# separate click events for each Row in listview on Android

Tags: java, android

How do I get separate Row Multi Textview on click event in Android?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle the click event in Listview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android)

Comment: you can not have separate click event for each row on listview..!! And if i have understood wrong please elaborate the question..!!

Answer (score 0):

You might have created the custom adapter for the list view 
Assuming you are using the viewholder pattern then you can set the click event in **adapter**