# Handling onClick with efficient ListView adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

Here's my `getView` function in a custom class extending `ArrayAdapter`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Thing p = getItem(position);
    Thing.ThingStatus thingStatus = p.getStatus();

    int thingStatusIcon; // change to thingStatusResource
    switch (thingStatus) {
        case A:
            thingStatusIcon = ICON_A;
            break;
        case B:
            thingStatusIcon = ICON_B;
            break;
        default:
            thingStatusIcon = ICON_C;
            break;

    }

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ThingRowHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        // If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
        viewHolder = new ThingRowHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thing_list_item, parent, false);
        // put these on the top like the colors
        viewHolder.thingIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thing_icon);
        viewHolder.thingId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thing_id_item);
        viewHolder.thingStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thing_status_item);
        // Cache the viewHolder object inside the fresh view
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // View is being recycled, retrieve the viewHolder object from tag
        viewHolder = (ThingRowHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.thingId.setText(p.getLpId());
    viewHolder.thingStatus.setText(thingStatus.toString());
    viewHolder.thingIcon.setImageResource(thingStatusIcon);
    viewHolder.position = position;
    return convertView;
}
```

I'm trying to add an `onClick` event listener for each row in my `ListView`. I tried setting the listener on `convertView` both inside the `if` statement and outside the `else` statement. I got mixed results. Sometimes the `onClick` wouldn't fire at all. Other times it would report the wrong position. I've scoured SO for examples of this and I'm surprised such a common functionality isn't well documented and/or not working in my case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

edit:

```
private class ThingRowHolder {
    ImageView thingIcon;
    TextView thingId;
    TextView thingStatus;
}
```

edit 2:

```
private void refreshList() {
    ArrayList<Thing> things = mThingContainer.getThings();
    Collections.sort(things);
    mThingListAdapter.refreshThings(things);
}
```

edit 3:

```
mThingListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ThingListAdapter.ThingRowHolder holder =
                (ThingListAdapter.ThingRowHolder) view.getTag();
        Thing p = mThingContainer.getThings().get(holder.position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle the click event in Listview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android)

Comment: @ShubhamShukla no, as my description states, I've already tried methods in other SO answers with no success

Comment: why you are setting listener in convertView.

Comment: @ShubhamShukla not sure where else to put it. I want the entire row to respond to the touch event rather than some element inside of it

Comment: then you should follow the above link.

Comment: @ShubhamShukla okay, I remember trying this solution. The problem is, I'm using the "optimized" listview where views are reused. So the position reported by the `onClick` isn't actually the view that was clicked. I'm not sure what the `getView` method on the other person's code looks like in order to be sure

Comment: then use listener in viewHolder

Comment: please clarify, the `viewHolder` is not actually a clickable view

Comment: post viewHolder class

Comment: @ShubhamShukla please see edit

Comment: `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` is what you want... Not sure why you are doing all this in the adapter. That is our point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set position as tag to your view,

```
convertview.setTag(R.id.thing_icon, position);
```

Now in your `onClick(View v)`,

```
int pos = (int)v.getTag(R.id.thing_icon);
Thing p = getItem(pos);
```

You can now use p as desired.

**Edit 1 : Updating data in adapter**

In your adapter, add the following method :

```
public void updateData(List<Thing> data) {
        if (data != null) {
            mData.clear();
            mData.addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now just call updateData method of adapter whenever you need to update the data.

Comment: This works, thanks! One small problem though, if a new item is added to the list, the positions when tapped are all shifted back one.

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() for your adapter on updating list data?

Whenever you update your data list, pass the updated list to your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged(), this will make the adapter update and redraw views based on your updated list.

Comment: I'm currently creating a new adapter for every refresh

Comment: That's not really recommended. I'll edit my ans and include updating data in adapter.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated

Comment: Still the same issue. Does it matter where I set the `mListView.onClickListener` ?

Comment: Can you post how you are updating list data which causes change in position?

Answer (score 0):

Use these inside your getView method

**If you want long click**

```
convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {}}
```

**if you want normal click**

```
   convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {}}
```