# How do implement ClickEvent on listview?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

What should I do to achieve Click Event on listview ?
Should I try OnItemClickListener or OnItemSelectedListener ?My code is here:

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.se_02.eventhand;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.usage.UsageEvents;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] foods = new String[] {"beef", "icecream", "sausage", "kebab", "falal", "zinger","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < foods.length; ++i ) {
            list.add(foods[i]);
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        final ListView Eventid = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Eventid);
        Eventid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="6dip" >

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/Eventid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried everything to achieve click event but it shows me error. how can I make it to work

Comment: *but it keeps up giving me error*  **care to share?**

Comment: Your problem is same and has been answered here. Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android

Comment: Use interface for communication between Your adapter and activity or fragment.

Comment: and only a hint: use RecyclerView instead of ListView, it has more advantages....

Answer (score 0):

This is how we set clicklistener in Listview.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
position, long id) {
        }
    });
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface internally in your adpater.

```
 public interface CallBack {
    void getData(Object obj1, Object obj2);
}
```

Initaliize it from reference from activity, either by constructor of adapter or making any method. I am using method for it

```
 public void setCallBack(CallBack callBack) {
    this.callBack= callBack;
}
```

In activity,

```
   adapter.setCallBack(new adapter.CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void getData(Object obj1, Object obj2) {        
            YOUR_DATA_TYPE data= (YOUR_DATA_TYPE) obj1;
            // code here what you want to do with data of clicked view of list.
        }
    });
```

Then inside your adapter, on any view click, set your value which you want to use :

```
 holder.View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            callBack.getData(YOUR_DATA,YOUR_DATA);

        }
    });
```

By using this technique, you can handle click on any view (like button,image etc) of row of list view or recylerview.

Answer (score 0):

```
Listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 switch (listview.getItemAtPosition (position) {
     case "beef" :
          //Do This
     break;
  }
 });
}
```