# Do setOnItemClickListener in listView which is made by of Arrayadapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, arraylist

Please help me, I want to show other activity when clicked in "about us", "more from us" of listView, how can I do that?

```
   ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

    words.add(new Word("About Us", R.id.main_images));
    words.add(new Word("More From Us", R.id.main_images));

    WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //what should I write here, so I can go other when clicked in listview
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain your code please? What is `R` for example? Some code is missing (`findViewById`)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle the click event in Listview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android)

Comment: I'm using R.id.main_images to import image in list view, and I'm using findViewById(R.id.list); because i've given the id of listView "list". please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a new Activity like this onItemClick

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
          Word word = words.get(i); // it's the selected word
          Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("word", word);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Make your `Word` class implement `Serializable/Parcelable`, this way only you can send it and extract in another `Activity` class.

In the `DetailsActivity` (or whatever name you have given to the second `Activity`), You can extract the selected word from extra like in `OnCreate` method.

```
Word word = (Word)(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("word"));
// Work on Word
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

@whoever is voting down answers, buddy we are just trying to help. I understand you don't get notification about being polite. The answer and question may not be clear to you but the answers here are relevant and related to the question.

Comment: I want to make intent when clicked in "more form us", "about us".. please help

Comment: I have edited the answer. This is should be understandable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an `intent` to do that.

Read this link to learn how to start another activity: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Answer (score -1):

Do it in your `onItemClick`:

```
Switch(i){
 case 0:
    // "About Us" is the first item in your list(position 0) and you can call it here, like
    startActivity(new Intent(this,AboutUsActivity.class))
    break;
case 1:
    // "More From Us" is the second item in your list(position 1) and you can call it here, like
    startActivity(new Intent(this,MoreAboutUs.class))
    break;
```

}

Comment: error is shown under "switch (i)", case 0:, case 1 and break by saying "cannot resolve"

Comment: I wrote it by hand but the answer must be something like this.